# Outlook 2010 randomly opening, stealing focus, opening multiple times

Tags: outlook, ms-office

Outlook 2010 on XP Pro

Usually with Firefox open, Outlook will go haywire.  It's spasmodically steal focus, open up multiple times and re-open if I close it.  I have no addins installed in it.  Strangely I ran office update yesterday and Windows downloaded an Office Compatibility Pack SP3 for Office 2007.  I've never had Office 2007 on this machine though.  Office Standard was purchased online and downloaded from the Microsoft site.  Word, PowerPoint and Excel (and Publisher - purchased separately) are not effected.

If I reboot, it'll usually be fine for some time, but that time period seems to be getting smaller and the issues more frequent.

I'm hesitant to delete my profile (I'm not even sure how a corrupted or damaged profile would cause Outlook to start when it's not running).

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question, flagged for superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You describe a situation when Firefox or its addons (Can you explore) is somehow interfering with the Outlook 2010.

1. XP is an old system. Outlook 2010 is a new sw. could be some compatibility problem but the fact that only Outlook, not Excel or Word is affected suggest otherwise.
2. Office Compatibility Pack may be relevant if you use any part of office, like Access Engine etc.  so nothing to worry about.
3. You need to narrow this down. Can you try to use Internet Explorer and not Firefox?
4. Other tools using Outlook - I have had some similar problems when new email message windows were opening randomly. The culprit was a dictionary which was reading clipboard and pressing buttons. Thus, can you try to disable all Windows startup items, reboot, and check if this helps?